# Does net/smtp send credentials in plain text?

Tags: security, email, go, smtp

I'm looking at this example. http://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#example_PlainAuth

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
    // Set up authentication information.
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "user@example.com", "password", "mail.example.com")

    to := []string{"recipient@example.net"}
    mesg := []byte("This is the email body.")

    err := smtp.SendMail("mail.example.com:25", auth, "sender@example.org", to, mesg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Does `smtp.PlainAuth` send credentials to the mail server in plain text? Is it safe to use net/smtp in the wild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlainAuth uses the Plain auth mech from RFC 4616, which is the username/password in plain cleartext.  Normally when you are using this, encryption will be handled at a lower level, for example you will create a TLS connection.   and then use PlainAuth over that.  If you are not talking over an encrypted connection, then use of PlainAuth can be risky as if the traffic is intercepted, the user/pass are easy to get.

but if you read, you will see the `SendMail` function says the following:

> SendMail connects to the server at addr, switches to TLS if possible, authenticates with the optional mechanism a if possible, and then sends an email from address from, to addresses to, with message msg.

So it will try to automatically upgrade to TLS where possible for you.  So as long as you are using servers that support TLS, you should be relatively safe.   The other Auth choice is CramMD5, but server support for this method is generally less common than PlainAuth which most everything supports.

Comment: How do I know if my server supports TLS? Do I need to install some other program? Do I need a TLS certificate on my end?

Comment: are you running your own server or using someone elses?  if you own? did you configure TLS / SSL on your MTA?   You would need an SSL certificate  configured ( it can be self signed,but you might run into issue with certain programs -- not sure about go, but assuming it is linked against openssl, then you might have issues with self signed)

Comment: Most of the time, I'm running my own server on DigitalOcean.

Comment: Then you would need to configure / enable tls as part of the server / droplet. If the code is running on the same server /droplet you probably won't need the auth / tls. As your attack surface in that case is minimal.

Comment: Is configuring TLS "as part of the server" similar to setting up TLS certs for a web server? Or is it a different process entirely?

Comment: Pretty much same thing and you can use the same cert / key. Just need to add the correct config.